# Creating a Truetype Font file with javafx

Tags: java, fonts, javafx-8, truetype

I have a canvas. It asks the user to draw a character from A-Z, a-z or 0-9. once the user draws a character say A, the current canvas object is saved in an arraylist of canvases. and another blank canvas pops up that asks the user to draw B. and so on.

The programs works fine. But I want to create a `.ttf` file with all the accepted characters drawn.

I have a button below the last displayed canvas which when clicked, will extract all chars from the arraylist of canvases and create a `.ttf` file from it. But how?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Fontastic](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/), a Java library for creating font files (including truetype fonts in .ttf files). Fontastic itself makes use of the library [doubletype](http://sourceforge.net/projects/doubletype/) to create truetype fonts. I'm not particularly familiar with those libraries though...

Comment: Can it detect my own handwriting from a piece of paper where I have written all the characters in a tabular format?

Comment: The point of this library is to create a font from scratch (by defining whatever vector graphics you want) or by modifying another font (which is already in a vector format). It won't convert a bitmap image (like your scanned sheet of paper) to vector fonts. I know that some vector graphics editors (like Inkscape) offer tools to help convert bitmaps to vectors, and some websites (like the free [myscriptfont](http://www.myscriptfont.com/)) offer to convert handwriting to truetype fonts, so it's certainly doable - but I don't know of any such tool available as a Java library.

Comment: Yeah I know about myscriptfont.com. But even that website converts a `png` image to `rtf`. How does it do? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **First Solution:**

You can use the [**java.awt.Font**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html), it is a Java class used to manage and create **Fonts**, you can use its [Font(String name, int style, int size)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) constructor to create your custom Font:

> **Font(String name, int style, int size):**
>
> Creates a new Font from the specified name, style and point size.
> The font name can be a font face name or a font family name. It is
> used together with the style to find an appropriate font face. When a
> font family name is specified, the style argument is used to select
> the most appropriate face from the family. When a font face name is
> specified, the face's style and the style argument are merged to
> locate the best matching font from the same family.
>
> For example if face name "Arial Bold" is specified with style
> Font.ITALIC, the font system looks for a face in the "Arial" family
> that is bold and italic, and may associate the font instance with the
> physical font face "Arial Bold Italic". The style argument is merged
> with the specified face's style, not added or subtracted. This means,
> specifying a bold face and a bold style does not double-embolden the
> font, and specifying a bold face and a plain style does not lighten
> the font.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *name* - the font name. This can be a font face name or a font family name, and may represent either a logical font or a
> physical font found in this GraphicsEnvironment. The family names for
> logical fonts are: Dialog, DialogInput, Monospaced, Serif, or
> SansSerif. Pre-defined String constants exist for all of these names,
> for example, DIALOG. If name is null, the logical font name of the new
> Font as returned by getName() is set to the name "Default".
>
> *style* -
> the style constant for the Font The style argument is an integer
> bitmask that may be PLAIN, or a bitwise union of BOLD and/or ITALIC
> (for example, ITALIC or BOLD|ITALIC). If the style argument does not
> conform to one of the expected integer bitmasks then the style is set
> to PLAIN.
>
> *size* - the point size of the Fon

And as you can see it allows you to create new Fonts depending on existing fonts, you can also change the style and the size.

This is [a Tutorial](http://www.java-examples.com/create-font-object-example) that you can follow.

---

## **Second Solution:**

As stated in comments, you can also use the **[Fontastic](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/)** Library which seems to be a great tool for creating new Fonts, It allows you to make fonts based on data, sensors, live feeds, or any other algorithm, or manipulate existing fonts to create your own version.

These are the basic steps needed to show you how it works. For a full reference see the [Documentation](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/#documentation).

How to create a new Fontastic object:

```
Fontastic f = new Fontastic(this, "ExampleFont");  // Create a new Fontastic object
```

How to set further font properties:

```
f.setAuthor("Andreas Koller");
```

How to create a glyph for the character A with a random shape of four points:

```
PVector[] points = new PVector[4];              // Define a PVector array containing the points of the shape
points[0] = new PVector(0, 0);                  // Start at bottom left
points[1] = new PVector(random(512), 0);        // The normal width is 512, the normal height 1024
points[2] = new PVector(random(512), random(1024)); // y coordinates are from bottom to top!
points[3] = new PVector(0, random(1024));

f.addGlyph('A').addContour(points);
```

How to generate the TrueType font file:

```
f.buildFont();
```

How to clean up afterwards:

```
f.cleanup();
```

You can see **[their examples](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/#examples)**.

---

## **Conclusion:**

But in the two cases you will not be able to create Fonts from handwritten scanned images, `Fantastic` won't allow you to create a Font from images but it uses vector graphics to create Fonts, so in this case the solution would be :

1. To use another tool to convert your images to vectors (**[Vector
   Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home)**, **[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)**, **[myScriptFont.com](http://www.myscriptfont.com/)**)
2. Then create your `Font` using the generated `vectors`.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this library: 
[fontastic font maker](http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/)

And that is how it works:

How to create a new Fontastic object:

```
Fontastic f = new Fontastic(this, "ExampleFont");  // Create a new Fontastic object
```

How to set further font properties:

```
f.setAuthor("Andreas Koller");                  // Set author name - will be saved in TTF file too
```

How to create a glyph for the character A with a random shape of four points(so here would be the points(or normalized points), which you have gathered before from user):

```
PVector[] points = new PVector[4];              // Define a PVector array containing the points of the shape
points[0] = new PVector(0, 0);                  // Start at bottom left
points[1] = new PVector(random(512), 0);        // The normal width is 512, the normal height 1024
points[2] = new PVector(random(512), random(1024)); // y coordinates are from bottom to top!
points[3] = new PVector(0, random(1024));

f.addGlyph('A').addContour(points);             // Assign contour to character A
```

How to generate the TrueType font file:

```
f.buildFont();                                  // Build the font resulting in .ttf and .woff files
                                                // and a HTML template to preview the WOFF
```